# Movie Identification: Werewolf and molotov cocktails

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to find the name of a movie.  It was a horror from the 80's most likely.  There was a bad guy that would transform into a werewolf like creature.  The protagonist was a young male about 18 years old.  I only caught the last 20-30 minutes of the movie.  The boy and his family (no dad that I remember) were hiding out in a cabin in the woods.  He was preparing for the bad guy to arrive by making molotov cocktails and other homemade weapons.  He also wields a lever action rifle.  Eventually, the bad guy shows up in his car, transforms, some molotov cocktails were thrown, the werewolf is injured, and the kid tracks him into the woods and kills him.  Anyone have any idea what movie this is?